# How to extract params from received link in react native firebase dynamiclink?

Tags: firebase, react-native, dynamic-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I tried to migrate from react navigation deeplinks to firebase dynamic linking using [this](https://rnfirebase.io/) library (react-native-firebase).
I have set up everthing and links are being generated and received on the app. However, is there any way to extract the params sent in the link properly using this library?. Currenty this is my code for handling received link:

```
  handleDynamicLink = () => {
    firebase
      .links()
      .getInitialLink()
      .then((url) => {
        console.tron.log('link is ', url);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.tron.log(error);
      });
  };
```

The url received is 
https://links.dev.customdomain.in/?link=products%2F1122
I want to extract the product id 1122 from the url. The only way for me right now is to parse the string and manually extract the relevant params. Unlike in react navigation deeplinks where I used to specify the path, like

```
   Product: {
      screen: Product,
      path: 'customdomain/products/:slug',
    },
```

Where the slug or id data used to pass as navigation param in the respective screen. Am I missing something? How can I pass mutliple params this way?

Answer (score 1):

Point 2 in this link [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.2.x/links/reference/links) says:

> The response contains the URL string only.

This means that the firebase.links().getInitialLink() method does not return query parameters, at least as at the time of writing this (v5.5.5). To add your paramaters, you should use a URL with your query param as part of the URL. What I mean is this

> Use  https://links.dev.customdomain.in/link/products/1122

and use Regex to extract the product id which is of interest to you. This is what works for me and I hope it helps.